# onclick of any link the web user control is loaded without post back

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

i have a aspx page and in which\

```
          Add Edit Delete
```

**ABC**                          GRIDVIEW

**DEF**

**GHI**

on click of any side link let ABC , DEF etc the Gridview related to that is opened
the gridview is in the Web user control and i have to show the gridview in the Placeholder dynamically.

in this case the whole page is not post back only the page in which the grid view is showing is post back and show the result.

please help and suggest me that how is it possible

Comment: Could you add more details and a better description? I can't get your idea from the text above

Comment: @Alexander Yezutov mainly the thing is i want to load the control on click of any link the page is not refreshed the only part of the page is refreshed in which the grid is to been shown

Comment: unable to understood ur point.Please Clarify more

Comment: http://codegod.org/WebAppCodeGod/UpdatePanel-tutorial-ASP-NET-AJAX-AID281.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using dynamically lodaed controls. For events to work, you have to recreate your control on everypostback(OnLoad), if not the event won't be fired.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to Submit the form in 'GRIDVIEW' by clicking on one of the links on the left?

You can trigger submit events through jQuery as follows:

```
$("#ABC_link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

This will submit the form, but presumably, you'll want to post the form to different locations regarding on which link is clicked?

I would suggest:

```
$("#ABC_link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#myForm").get(0).setAttribute('action', 'myCorrectActionValue'); //this works, similar commands tend to fail silently
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```